# taskbar USB device mount indicator

Tags: usb

Is there available an add-on Task-bar indicator to show mounted usb devices and enable safe removal?

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Schyken's answer you can find all of the wingpanel indicators made by the elementary team on the Github here: https://github.com/elementary?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=wingpanel&type=&language=.

Perhaps you can suggest an indicator in an issue or alternatively just use GNOME which has a [Removable Drive Menu](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/7/removable-drive-menu/) shell extension.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't a USB/mount manager for the system tray.